# instagram-private-api throwing an error while trying to post an image on Instagram

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

```
const IgApiClient = require('instagram-private-api').IgApiClient;
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.json');

const ig = new IgApiClient();
ig.state.generateDevice(config.instagramUsername);
ig.state.proxyUrl = config.igProxy;

async function uploadImage(imageBuffer) {
  const imageUrl = await ig.upload.photo(
    {
        file: imageBuffer
    }
  );
  console.log(`URL: ${imageUrl}`);
}

(async () => {
  await ig.simulate.preLoginFlow();
  const loggedInUser = await ig.account.login(config.instagramUsername, config.instagramPassword);
  process.nextTick(async () => await ig.simulate.postLoginFlow());

  const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync('output.png');

  uploadImage(imageBuffer);
})();
```

Error:

> C:\Users\PC\Desktop\spotted\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\core\request.js:126
> return new errors_1.IgResponseError(response);
> ^
>
> IgResponseError: POST /rupload_igphoto/1672943340753_0_8268117741 - 400 Bad Request;
> at Request.handleResponseError (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\spotted\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\core\request.js:126:16)
> at Request.send (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\spotted\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\core\request.js:54:28)
> at async UploadRepository.photo (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\spotted\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\repositories\upload.repository.js:18:26)
> at async uploadImage (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\spotted\bomba.js:10:20)
>
> Node.js v19.2.0

Hello, I've been trying to create an app, which will automatically post generated images on instagram, but there's a problem, it doesn't work even if i do it as it is intended in documentation (probably). Does anyone have any ideas?